# How can we get iframe current url in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am creating a simple react App. In react component, I am using Iframe. Now I want to access the current URL from the iframe. while the user clicks the website page link it goes to another page and the URL changes. how can access that current URL?
My code is below:
In App.Js File

`<IframeComponent src="http://scratchpads.org/" height="100%" width="45%"/>`

and it is Component code:

```
 import React from 'react';
export default class IframeComponent extends React.Component {
    myOnloadFunction = () =>{
    console.log(this.props.src)
   // document.getElementById('frame').src =  "http://scratchpads.org/"
    console.log(document.getElementById('frame').src)
//    console.log(document.frames['frame'].document.location)
    }
  render() {  
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe src={this.props.src} height={this.props.height} width={this.props.width}  className="fullheight" onLoad={this.myOnloadFunction} id = "frame"  /> 
      </div>
        )}}
```

Comment: Navigating inside the iframe, does not change the iframe element’s `src` property content. And any access to the actual window object instance of the iframe is forbidden, if the iframe content is from a different origin. So if that’s your situation here, then the answer is simply: What you want, is not possible.

Comment: In a possible sense can you please write sample code?

Comment: No, we can't provide sample code, as it's not possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is forbidden , if the iframe url is different , it cannot be altered and it cannot access the parent website data

Comment: Is there any method to access the iframe URL in react component?